# Factoring functions out of integrals(?)

Tags: calculus, integration

This is kinda silly:

If I have an integral in the form $\int \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$, is this ever equivalent to saying $\frac{1}{g(x)}\int f(x)dx$? There's obviously many many examples where this doesn't work but can it ever work?

Comment: Too obvious? $g(c)=const (\not=0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are integrating with respect to $x$, you cannot just factor out a function of $x$ from the integral. The only cases in which this would work are when $g(x)$ is a non zero constant. For instance, $\int{\frac{x}{2}dx}=\frac{1}{2}\int{xdx}$.